# How do I listen for HTMLEditor getting or losing focus?

Tags: javafx, focus, html-editor

I need to track when an HTMLEditor element in JavaFX gets focus or loses it. I used a listener for textArea, but it doesn't work in this case.

```
        htmlEditor.focusedProperty().addListener(((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->{
        if (newValue) { 
           // focus received
           
        }else{ 
           //focus is lost
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did face the same issue while adding a `ChangeListener` to the focused Property where the listener was not being invoked. However, there is another possible workaround for this. You can simply access your `Scene`'s focus owner `Node` and add a `ChangeListener` to it to detect the old and new focused `Node` which in your case is an `HTMLEditor` control which is a `Node` of type `WebView`. The code would look something like this:

```
scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldNode, newNode) -> {
            if(newNode instanceof WebView)
            {
                System.out.println("HTML Editor focused");
                // do something when HTMLEditor gets focused
            }
            else if(oldNode instanceof WebView) {
                System.out.println("HTML Editor focus lost");
                // do something when HTMLEditor loses focused
            }
        });
```